# Problem about degree of a polynomial and determinant

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant

[image]

answer is: $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $2$

I couldn't proceed even the first step to find out the answer. please help

Comment: Why don't you compute the Determinante?

Comment: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real numbers and the sum of their squares is negative,  then any answer is ok. If  they are not, it would be nice if you specify the domain. ..

Answer (score 1):

From a determinant, we can take values out from a row or a column and still end up with the same result. So, we can take $(1 + a^2)$ common from the first column, $(1 + b^2)$ common from the second column, and $(1 + c^2)$ common from the third column to arrive at:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
(1 + a^2)(1 + b^2)(1 + c^2)
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1 + a^2x}{1 + a^2} & x & x \\
x & \frac{1 +b^2x}{1 + b^2} & x\\
x & x & \frac{1+c^2x}{1 + c^2}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

At this point, we can evaluate the determinant quite easily and notice that the answer will be a second degree polynomial